# Show that $\sqrt{n}(X_n - \mu) \xrightarrow{D} X \implies X_n \xrightarrow{p} \mu$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

This is what I've done so far:

$F_{\sqrt{n}(X_n - \mu)}(t) \xrightarrow[\text{n $\rightarrow \infty$ }]{} F_{X}(t)$ for every $t \in R$ where $F_X$ is continuous.

Thus, $P(X_n - \mu \le \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{n}}) \xrightarrow[\text{n $\rightarrow \infty$ }]{} P(X \le t) \iff 1 - P(X_n - \mu \ge \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{n}}) \xrightarrow[\text{n $\rightarrow \infty$ }]{} P(X \le t)$

$\iff 1 - P(X_n - \mu \ge \dfrac{-t}{\sqrt{n}}) + P(\lvert X_n - \mu \rvert \ge \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{n}}) \xrightarrow[\text{n $\rightarrow \infty$ }]{} P(X \le t)$

If I somehow manage to prove that $P(X_n - \mu \le \dfrac{-t}{\sqrt{n}}) \xrightarrow[\text{n $\rightarrow \infty$ }]{} P(X \le t)$, then $X_n \xrightarrow{p} \mu$, no? This idea doesn't seem too farfetched to me, given that $P(X_n - \mu \le \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{n}}) \xrightarrow[\text{n $\rightarrow \infty$ }]{} P(X \le t)$. However, with little  information about $F_{X_n - \mu}$ and its coninuity, I'm unsure of how to finish the proof with this approach.
I'd appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: This follows from a direct application of [Slutky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) in the form $X_n\Longrightarrow X$ and $Y_n\Longrightarrow c$, $c$ constant, then $X_nY_n\Longrightarrow cX$ along with  the fact that $Y_n\Longrightarrow c$ iff $Y_n\rightarrow c$ in probability. In your case $X_n-\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)\Longrightarrow0 X=0$ as $Y_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $P(X_n-\mu>\epsilon) =P(\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)>\epsilon\sqrt{n})$.

Fix $\delta>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ and choose a continuity point $x$ of $F_X$ so large that $1-F_X(x) <\delta$. If $n$ is so large that $\epsilon\sqrt{n}>x$, then
$$
P(X_n-\mu>\epsilon) =P(\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)>\epsilon\sqrt{n})\le P(\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)>x),
$$
and so
$$
\limsup_n P(X_n-\mu>\epsilon)\le \lim_n P(\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)>x)=1-F_X(x)<\delta.
$$
It follows that $\limsup_n P(X_n-\mu>\epsilon)=0$. Likewise, $\limsup_n P(X_n-\mu<-\epsilon)=0$. Therefore $\lim_n P(|X_n-\mu|>\epsilon)=0$.